# Readable key value pair data-structure in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods, field

I have a key value arrays

```
String[] fields      = {"firstName", "middleName", "id"};
String[] fieldValues = {"first name", "middle name", "student id"};
```

I have a method that compares two beans and returns a array of String with different field values.

```
 public static String[] beanCompare(Object A, Object B, 
                                          String[] fields, String[] fieldValue);
```

Example If I pass a Studentbean with different firstName and id. 
It will return

> `["first name", "student id"]`.

I need to compare 100's of beans.
The return value updates an activity log table. Let say, the firstName field is updated. We display

> the `first name` has been updated

in the UI. It's for auditing.
 Is there a readable and maintainable way to represent such key-value pair?

Comment: considered java 8 lambda streaming ? You will always need a 'mapper' between the 2 lists

Comment: Aheum... where are you using the fieldValues?

Comment: `fieldValues` is not being used in your method. What is it for?

Comment: My apology. I tried to write a simplified version of my large method. The field is the value we get after parsing our bean. The value is the name we want to display. Eg: firstName : backend value and Student first name : UI Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, enum worked for me.

```
    public enum FieldEnum {

    firstName("first name"), middleName("middle name"), id("student id");

    String value;

    FieldEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    }
```

Its more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that (passing field names and field values this way) you're trying to build custom objects dynamically.

If that's your purpose, then you're in full [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/214186), since you've figured out this solution to your problem, and then you're trying to tune up this solution, while you should go back to the problem, which *has* a standard, engineered, best practice solution: the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

If you have many fields on an object, but you need to use only a portion of them in some cases and another portion in other cases, then use a **Builder**, set only the fields you need, then invoke the `build()` method, and get your object without the need to do what you're doing or permute all the constructors.

[**Here** is an example](https://jlordiales.me/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/) of this pattern in Java.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to build custom objects dynamically. 
I have a very diverse set of fields. I can't create a builder for all the different methods. So, I thought of using an array of strings to build my object dynamically. 
Thank you for the XY problem link. 
I have created a builder class to get the list of field string but can I use the builder pattern to accommodate the dynamic behaviour?

Comment: That's exactly what the Builder pattern is for. If you have 100 fields, you only need to create 100 setter method on the builder, instead of the permutations needed for all the different constructors (which mathematically would be 100*99/2 = 4950 constructors to cover all cases). Also try avoiding such huge beans, by splitting data in more atomic beans, but if you can't, Builder pattern is your best friend here

Comment: Hi. My apology for not being able to explain my situations as clearly as I intended. I am using builder pattern already. I have 100's of beans. I need to compare two objects of the same bean. And so I have the field and values array. I was looking for a way to represent it more effectively. I believed I fell into the XY pit. 

Comment: I guess so :) Feel free to edit your question by adding your real, underlying problem, with a meaningful example (even a *foo-bar* one, but clear enough to let us understand *exactly* what you're trying to achieve)

Comment: I have edited. I hope I have avoided the XY problem this time. Please let me know If my example is not clear enough.

Comment: But what do you do once you have a list of values which differ ? What's their purpose ? Also the returned values are unrelated to the input values, since they're a subset; how do you correlate the returned values with the field they are representing ?

Comment: The return value updates an activity log table. Let say, the firstName field is updated. We display the `first name` has changed in the UI. It's for auditing.

Comment: Mmh ok, I got it. I guess it highly depends on the rest of your code... BTW this seems an even more appropriate question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than for StackOverflow, since it works, and you simply want to refactor and polish it.